# Sending iphone's [[UIDevice currentDevice] name] over network

Tags: iphone, nsstring, uidevice, cfnetwork

I'm trying to send the device name over a network implemented with CFNetwork. My application will successfully send the NSString over the simulator, but not on an actual device. The class reference has the properties for this function set at:

```
@propertyic,readonly,retain) NSString *name
```

I've tried formatting the final string I intend to use by using stringWithFormat as well as stringByAppendingString but it won't work using either method.

Comment: Silly question maybe but is the name set on the device?

Comment: What protocol you use for transferring device name over network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First try to send a a stupid name that you create, like

```
NSString *nameTest = @"Name of iPad"
```

If you see this, the problem is not send a NSString, I think this is working for you. Than, you know get the name with this

```
NSString *name = [[UIDevice currentDevice] name];
```

Now the bug you can have is: A nill name or name with invalid character, this work for me:

```
NSArray *toRemove = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"'", @"\"", @"<", @">", nil];
for (NSString *currentChar in toRemove) {
    name = [name stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:currentChar 
                                           withString:@""];
}    
if ([name isEqualTo:@""]) name = @"no name";
```

See if this is the problem